# How to get the delta of changeLogs in Liquibase

Tags: liquibase, delta

My requirement is to make liquibase generate only the updated **changeSets** from the DB compared to the previous **chnageSets**.

Let's say I have two tables t1 and t2 in my postgresql , so in my **changeLog** two **changeSets** are present. Below is for understanding:

```
<changelog>
    <changeSet> t1 </changeSet>
    <changeSet> t2 </changeSet>
</changelog>
```

Now, when i create one more table t3, the **changeLog** would be like below:

```
<changelog>
    <changeSet> t1 </changeSet>
    <changeSet> t2 </changeSet>
    <changeSet> t3 </changeSet> 
</changelog>
```

Instead of that I want the liquibase to generate the thing similar to the below which is the updated change:

```
<changelog>
    <changeSet> t3 </changeSet> 
</changelog>
```

So that It would be convenient to send the updated changes across the DBs.

Comment: If change sets t1 and t2 are already applied, it wont run again(default). So, in effect only t3 will get applied.

Comment: Rajeev, I saw this question on our old Liquibase forum, but got left off the migration.  If you have more questions, please try the new https://forum.liquibase.org or Liquibase has a chat forums on discord as well: https://discord.gg/RDuuVP

Answer (score 0):

the spirit of liquibase is to manage the db schema. The tool changeLogGenerate is useful to startup a project but it is not design to create delta over versions.

Liquibase has to be the source, not the consequence.

Eric

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new database within [`PostgreSQL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createdatabase.html) and if the according schema if it is not part of your `changeLogFile`
2. `Update` the new database with your initial changelog (the one with t1 and t2)
3. You can now use the [`diffChangeLog`](https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/community/diffchangelog.html) command poiting the `--referenceUrl` to the new created database and `--changeLogFile` to your changed changeLog (the one with t1, t2 and t3). It will create the `changeLog` with the difference which in your case should be t3. If needed you can specify the output via `--outputFile`